# C# attributes vs configuration files

Tags: c#, configuration

I just thought about configuration in C# and wondered why I should ever use an Attribute. I have to recompile my code when I change an attribute, so it's not as dynamic as an configuration file. If these values should only be edited by developers why don't we use just  hard coded configuration objects which would be faster than reflection or files to be really dynamic ?

Comment: I believe you may be confusing what attribute are and what contexts they are used. While attribute can be used to store configuration values, they are not configuration. Attribute are metadata about the class on which they are used. While some may use it to store configuration, you for yourself already see why that may not be one of the best design choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may be confusing what attribute are and under what contexts they are used.

While an attribute can be used to store configuration values, they are not configuration as compared to configuration file values. So the comparison between attributes and configuration files is also misplaced.

Attributes are metadata about the class on which they are used.

Reference [Attributes (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)

> Attributes provide a powerful method of associating metadata, or declarative information, with code (assemblies, types, methods, properties, and so forth).

While some may use it as a configuration store, you for yourself already see why that may not be one of the best design choices.

Comment: Yes it is meta data, but why should I do that if I don't want to do anything with that information ? So there's still no advantage over other approaches in cases like ORM-Attributes, etc. So the question is when I write my own serialization mechanism why should I prefer attributes over the other alternatives ?

Comment: I guess the answer to your question is that the attributes are more localized. And by localized I mean that they are bundled to a "decorated" class, property or method, and you can access them throught reflection dynamically at the runtime when processing your types. In other words, it is "more convenient" for some scenarios.